# how to inflate a view on click of cardview?

Tags: android, view, android-inflate

Any Idea how to inflate this type of view on click of `CardView`. And how to design corner like this in image?

[image: how to inflate view like this]

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: on click of CardView open dialog and set 9patch image to that dialog

Comment: Use 9-patch images.

Comment: any example or link you having?

Comment: add your onItemClickListner code

Comment: @i_m_mahii `onBindViewHolder` I added my holder.item.setOnClickListener. But i don't think so its needed. Because i don't wrote any code for inflating this type of layout

Comment: this is just a `PopupWindow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used PopupWindow , which resolved my issue

```
   final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow();
            View layout = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
            try {
                final Button b1 = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.cancel_action);
                final  Button b2 = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.quantity_action);
                final Button b3 = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.link_action);
                b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        paymentoptionedt.setText("Cash");
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Cash",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        popup.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        paymentoptionedt.setText("Card");
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Card",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        popup.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        paymentoptionedt.setText("Link Pay");
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Link Pay",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        popup.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            popup.setContentView(layout);
            popup.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popup.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            popup.setFocusable(true);
            popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
            popup.showAsDropDown(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the OnClick you can show a `PopupWindow`. Create the xml layout for it as you would any other layout and then in the `onCreateView`/`onCreate` inflate the view like so

`View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);`.

From there you just have to create and configure the PopupWindow.

`PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popupView);`

Then in your onClickListener call `popup.showAsDropDown(anchor);`.

Regarding the corner you should be able to create it in xml using a square/rectangle shape and then rotate it to make the triangle. From there just include it in your R.layout.popup

Check out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html for its apis and how you can configure it.